# How to work with Facebook authentication in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, xamarin.auth

I'm building an Android app with Xamarin.Android. I am using Facebook for user login and I also need few other permissions like `user_events`, `rsvp_event` etc. But I don't understand the exact steps that I should follow. I've read the docs, but I'm still confused.

Do I have to create a Facebook app first and approve the permissions?

How do I test the app with FB login while the app is in beta stage?

If anyone can point me to the right direction with all the steps that I need to follow, it will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered in several places. Short answer: **No**, you **don't** need to submit for review for testing login or permissions.

I will quote this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/faqs#what_is_review):

> **Note**: People who are listed in your app's Roles tab will have access
>   to extended permissions without going through review (e.g.
>   `publish_actions` or `manage_pages`). For example, if you use the Facebook
>   Plugin for Wordpress to publish your blog posts to your Facebook Page
>   or Profile, you do not need to submit for review so long as all your
>   publishers are listed in your app's Roles tab.
>
> Also, if you're the developer of an app and are the only person using
>   it, then your app doesn't need to go through review. Since you're the
>   developer, all app capabilities should be available. You will still
>   need to take your app out of developer mode, but you should be able to
>   do that without going through review.